# Firebase pagination not working when fetching posts from different users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently building an app in which there is a main feed that shows the posts from all the people that you are following. When you follow someone, all of their posts are added to your "feed". In my firebase database, there is a feed node that holds references to the posts of everyone you are following, including the posts that the current user creates themselves. I have a function 'loadPosts()' that fetches the reference to each user post, fetches the data for the post, and then adds that data into an array which is then shown in a collectionView.

I am trying to paginate this data from firebase with a query based on "creationDate" and my code works when I am not following anyone, but as soon as I follow someone with a different userId, the main feed begins to duplicate posts and not order them correctly. Here's what a snapshot of the data I am fetching looks like:

[image]

In simple terms, the data structure is:

```
  "feed": {
            "uid": {
                "post1Key": {
                    "creationDate",
                    "post_uid"
                },
                "post2Key": {
                    "creationDate",
                    "post_uid"
                },
            }
        }
```

The "post_uid" property is the uid of the user who created the post and the "creationDate" property is the time at which the post was created. Below is the loadPosts() function:

```
 static func loadPosts(posts: [Postt], isFinishedPaging: Bool, completion: @escaping ([Postt], Bool) -> Void) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    var pagingTemp = isFinishedPaging
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("feed").child(uid)
    var query = ref.queryLimited(toLast: 4).queryOrdered(byChild: "creationDate")
    if posts.count > 0 {
        let value = posts.last?.creationDate.timeIntervalSince1970
        query = query.queryEnding(atValue: value)
    }
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var completedPosts = [Postt]()
        guard var allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

        allObjects.reverse()
        if allObjects.count == 0 || allObjects.count == 1 {
            pagingTemp = true
        }
        if  posts.count > 0 && allObjects.count > 0 {
            allObjects.removeFirst()
        }
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        for postData in allObjects {
            guard let postDict = postData.value as? [String : Any],
                let postId = postDict["post_uid"] as? String
                else { return }
            dispatchGroup.enter()

            PostClient.show(forKey: postData.key, uid: postId) { (post) in
                if let post = post {
                    completedPosts.append(post)
                }
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            completion(completedPosts, pagingTemp)
        })
    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch posts: ", err)
    }
}
```

Then there's a function called show(forKey,uid) which returns a Post object from the reference that is fetched in the loadPosts():

```
   static func show(forKey postKey: String, uid: String, completion: @escaping (Postt?) -> Void) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).child(postKey)
    var images = [String]()
    Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid) { (user) in
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let post = Postt(snapshot: snapshot) else {
            return completion(nil)
        }
        let imageRef = ref.child("images")
        imageRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (imageSnapshot) in
        guard let values = imageSnapshot.value as? [String] else {return}
        values.forEach({ (value) in
            images.append(value)
        })
        post.imageUrls = images
        post.user = user
        completion(post)
        })
    })
   }
 }
```

The problem is not rooted in the show() function, it is simply the fact that the posts are not being returned in the proper order.

This loadPosts() function is then called in the viewDidLoad method of the collectionView:

```
    self.posts.removeAll()

    self.isFinishedPaging = false

    UserClient.loadPosts(posts: self.posts, isFinishedPaging: isFinishedPaging) { (posts, pagingResult) in
        self.posts = posts
        self.isFinishedPaging = pagingResult
        if self.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: We're missing a lot of context here. What is the meaning of the level in your data structure? What is a "feed"? What is "following someone"? I highly recommend reproducing the problem in a [minimal, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as that makes it much more likely that someone can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok I clarified the issue

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm having the same issue.